# Spark Driver supervise does not work reliably

Tags: apache-spark

I have a standalone cluster setup. I DO NOT have a streaming use case. I use AWS EC2 machines to have spark master and worker processes.

**Problem**: If a spark worker machine running some drivers and executor dies, then the driver is not spawned again on other healthy machines.

**Below are my findings:**

```
| Action/Behaviour    | Executor                     | Driver                       |
|---------------------|------------------------------|------------------------------|
| Worker Machine Stop | Relaunches on other machines | NO Relaunch                  |
| kill -9 to process  | Relaunches on other machines | Relaunches on other machines |
| kill to process     | Relaunches on other machines | Relaunches on other machines |
```

**Cluster Setup:**

1. I have a spark standalone cluster
2. `spark.driver.supervise=true`
3. Spark Master HA is enabled and is backed by zookeeper
4. Spark version = 2.4.4
5. I am using a systemd script for the spark worker process

Comment: I always learnt Spark Driver is single point of failure.

Comment: But then shouldn't Spark Master kickstart the dead Driver process?  `spark.driver.supervise` is set to true.

Answer (score 0):

The Spark Driver is a single point of failure in Spark applications.

If the Driver is killed, then related Tasks are obviated as there is no Driver.

For Spark Streaming with Check-pointing there is recovery.

Comment: But then why when we send `kill -9` and `kill` signals, the driver gets relaunched? I was checking source code for spark and what I found was that the spark worker process does monitoring of driver and executor states. If these state gets changed, they notify the master process. In the case of the machine going down, even the spark worker process is going down, so probably he can not communicate with master. But then logically, the master knows everything, so shouldn't master spawn the dead drivers on other machines?

Comment: Not how I learnt it. Surprise me - may be things have changed but I answer your question as far as I know from where I worked in the past as well. AWS EC2 setup as well.

Comment: The Spark driver is a single point of failure because it holds all cluster state for the running App. So...